# How to have code folding for Genie (.gs files) in Geany IDE

Tags: code-snippets, geany, code-folding, genie

It seems that Geany does not handle code in Genie programming language very well. It does not offer code folding nor specific snippets.

- How to have code folding in Geany for the Genie programming language?
- Does anyone has snippets to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get code folding open up (or create) the file:

```
~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.Genie.config
```

and add or edit the section [lexer_properties] to:

```
[settings]
# Vala uses the C lexer
lexer_filetype=Python
tag_parser=Python
```

For the snippets, here are snippets based on Genie's tutorial. Just add them by navigating the menu to Tools>Configuration files>snippets.conf and add the following:

```
[Genie]
if=if %cursor%a > 0\n\t%cursor%
ifdo=if %cursor%a > 0 do %cursor%
else=else if %cursor% is %cursor%\n\t%cursor%
for=for var %cursor%i = 1 to 10\n\t
fordo=for %cursor%s in %cursor%args do %cursor%print s
whiledo=while %cursor% do %cursor%
while=while %cursor%\n\t%cursor%
do=%cursor%count:int = 1\ndo\n\t%cursor%print "%i", count\n\tcount++\nwhile %cursor%count <= 10
case=case %cursor%a\n\twhen %cursor%0,1,2\n\t\t%cursor%print "a is less than 3"\n\twhen %cursor%3 \n\t\t%cursor%print "a is 3"\n\tdefault\n\t\t%cursor%print "a is greater then 3"
try=try%block%\ncatch (%cursor%)%block_cursor%
def=def %cursor%(%cursor%a:%cursor%string):%cursor%Type\n\t%cursor%
class=class %cursor%Foo:%cursor%Object\n\t%cursor%i:int\n\t%cursor%init\n\t\t%cursor%print "something"\n\tfinal\n\t\t%cursor%print "finalizing"\n\tconstruct( %cursor%:%cursor% )\n\t\t%cursor%a=b
array=%cursor%tokens : array of string = {%cursor%"This", "Is", "Genie"}
list=var %cursor%l = new list of string\n%cursor%l.add()
dictstrg=var %cursor%d = new dict of string,string
dictint=var %cursor%d = new dict of string,int
try=try\n\t%cursor%fn("home/jamie/test")\nexcept %cursor%ex : %cursor%IOError\n\t%cursor%print "Error: %s", ex.message
```

I am just a learner, so be free to change it to your will.

Comment: No need to add a new config it's already part of Geanys core distribution https://github.com/geany/geany/blob/master/data/filetypes.Genie.conf -- Please rather upgrade and may fill a bugreport.

Comment: Hi! @Luís, I must say it is perfect! but in  comment line, (or lines)? It can't show it correctly,

Comment: Yeah I later noticed that too. No clue how to solve that though.